# Question Regarding Linear ODE-Trouble Using Integrating Factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integration

Consider the equation $$\frac{dy}{dx} + 5y = e^{2x}$$
One method of attack as far as i know is to multiply both sides by $e^{5x}$.This gives $$e^{5x}\frac{dy}{dx} + y5e^{5x} = e^{2x}e^{5x} = e^{7x}$$
We now find that the LHS is,in fact,the derivative of $ye^{5x}$.
$$\therefore \frac{d}{dx}(ye^{5x}) = e^{7x}$$
Now what do i do?Integrate this way$$\int\frac{d}{dx}(ye^{5x}) = \int e^{7x} ?$$

Comment: exactly! you have solved it in the first place, why post it :)

Comment: Oh is it?I thought till the time you finish integrating the desired function it would still be considered unsolved.I don't know man.

Comment: I mean you have reached a stage where 'solving it further' is a mere formality. If you are confused wrt $dx$, just take it to RHS as Paul says and you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From
$$\frac{d}{dx}(ye^{5x}) = e^{7x},$$
we get
$$\int d(ye^{5x}) =\int e^{7x}dx,$$
which implies that
$$ye^{5x}=\frac{1}{7}e^{7x}+C.$$

Comment: Oh can we still can use $dx$ as a factor even though $\frac{d}{dx}(ye^{5x}) = e^{7x}$ is in $\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)) = f(x)$ form?I need some insight on this.

Comment: I am not sure...but that is  what normally people do: If we have a differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x)$, after multiplying the integrating factor $I(x)=e^{\int P(x)dx}$, the differetial equation $I(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+I(x)P(x)y=Q(x)I(x)$ reduces to $\frac{d}{dx}(I(x)y)=I(x)Q(x)$. Then we can solve the equation by $\int d(I(x)y)=\int I(x)Q(x)dx$.

Comment: yes exactly  @Paul, author of this question  can also use wolframalpha to make sure  how to solve such probblems

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's what you do.

Look at what you have: $${d\over dx} (ye^{5x}) = e^{7x}.$$ 
This is saying that $ye^{5x}$ is an antiderivative of $e^{7x}$. Thus, you can write 
$$\tag{1}ye^{5x} =\int e^{7x}\, dx;$$
after all, the indefinite integral of a function is its general antiderivative.

At this point, you then evaluate the integral in (1) and solve for $y$.